# Merging multiple tasks to reduce the output

Tags: ansible

We are trying to get lesser output while executing a playbook on multiple OS flavours. But unable to find a solution hence posting is here for a better answer.

As we get multiple task executed, is it possible to merge into one. We are collecting the output in a file & then will veryfy the same with different tags.

```
- name: verify hostname
  block:
    - name: read hostname [PRE]
      shell: hostname
      register: hostname
    - name: set fact [hostname]
      set_fact:
        results_pre: "{{ results_pre | combine({'hostname': hostname.stdout.replace(\"'\", '\"')|quote }) }}"
    - name: write hostname
      copy:
        dest: "{{ remote_logs_path }}/{{ ansible_ssh_host }}/pre/hostname"
        content: "{{ hostname.stdout }}"
  tags:
    - pre
```

Current output

```
TASK [role : read hostname [PRE]] ***************************************************************************
changed: [ip]

TASK [role : set fact [hostname]] ***************************************************************************
ok: [ip]

TASK [role : write hostname] ********************************************************************************
changed: [ip]
```

Required Output

```
TASK [role : Hostname Collected] ********************************************************************************
    changed: [ip]
```

Comment: Are you aware ansible provides the fact `ansible_hostname` out of the box? You just need to gather facts which is the default.

Comment: @Zeitounator: Above is just an example for hostname, but there are many other tasks for which I am trying to merge the output. Like collecting the subscription status, multipath status etc...

Comment: Have you given consideration to the [`dense` stdout callback](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/general/dense_callback.html), or perhaps [`selective`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/general/selective_callback.html)?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. On the three tasks you provide, one is useless: `set fact [hostname]` because your are never using this fact in the end. So, removing it along with using Ansible facts, as pointed by Zeitounator makes it a one task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's a bad idea to parse Ansible output. You may get some runtime warnings or unexpected additional lines.

If you really want to stick to Ansible output, there are a so-called `callback plugins`, you may try to implement your own if you want.

If you need some report from Ansible playbook, the common pattern is to have a separate task, which reports into a file (usually, on a controller host, using `delegate: localhost`).

Finally, if you want to check for idempotence, Molecule provides this feature.

Comment: How can we analyse status of which task was successful and failed. If we don’t collect the output.

Comment: You can set `any_errors_fatal: true` for playbook, in this case any error would cause ansible-playbook to set exit code 2.